# Unable to update safari due to "Spotlight is using the SafariQuickLookPreview extension"

Tags: macos, safari, mojave, spotlight

Error message:

> Spotlight is using the SafariQuickLookPreview extension, which must be
>   closed before the software can be installed.

[image]

I have already closed safari.

What do I need to do to update safari?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This seems to work for me.

Go to `Activity` and search for 'safari':

[image]

Pick the entry 'SafariQuickLookPreview (Spotlight)' entry and kill it.

Then use the 'Try Again' button in the 'Software Update' pane in System Preferences.

Comment: There is no 'Kill' command on Activity Monitor 10.14 (GB English). 'Quit' didn't work. 'Force Quit' did. So this works for me   

Answer (score 0):

From a Terminal window you can also just kill the `SafariQuickLookPreview` process as follows:

```
pkill -9 SafariQuickLookPreview
```